# Understand C bit macros

Tags: c, bitmap, macros

From the Practical C book there is a section on bit maps and setting/testing bits. This is the example to set bits.

```
#define SET_BIT(x,y) graphics[(x)/8][y] |= (0x80 >>((x)%8))
```

Now, I understand this until the "|=" how does that operation 'set' bits? It's comparing the input of SET_BIT(x) against a mask, i think, where does this mask come from?

0x80 >> shifts bits from the far left (10000000), how far depends on the result of (x)%8, and the reason it is "%8" is because there are 8 bits in the byte "x". Am I understanding this correctly?

Here is the full code from exercise 11-1, which includes TEST_BIT and CLEAR_BIT macros. 
[exercise 11-1](https://github.com/tangledhelix/practical-c-programming/blob/master/chap_11/11-1/bit_ops.c)

Comment: Do not use this on signed integers! It might not yield what is intended. And whether a bytes has 8 bits depends on the implementation. You should check `CHAR_BIT` first.

Answer (score 1):

The `|=` operator performs an in-place bitwise OR.  Since you are only shifting a single bit, then only one bit will be modified in the result.  The rest of the value will be unchanged.

The `x` and `y` are an image address.  The `x` is divided by 8 to give a byte address, and then the modulo by 8 takes care of the bit address.

Answer (score 0):

The mask is constructed by `(0x80 >>((x)%8))`. As you note, it right-shifts `0b10000000` by `x % 8`. The byte is selected by `(x)/8` in the array access, then the bit is selected by the mask.

`|=` is an augmented assignment operation, and it sets a bit because the bitwise OR operation returns 1 in in the result position if the bit in that position is set in either operand, and the flag guarantees that for the bit we want to set.
For example, `10000000 | 00001000` is `10001000`

Note that `foo |= bar;` is equivalent to `foo = foo | bar;`

Further examples:

- `SET_BIT(5,1)` will give `graphics[0][1] |= 4;` (4 is `0b00000100`)
- `SET_BIT(21,1)` will give `graphics[2][1] |= 4;` (4 is `0b00000100`, but we're operating on a different byte here)

As pointed out by Olaf in the comments, any program that uses this should only use it on unsigned integers (because the implementation of signed integers could effect your results in some interesting ways), and should check that `CHAR_BIT` is 8.

Answer (score 0):

well `a |= b`is just shorthand for `a = a | b` ... given that and the knowledge that `|` is the "bitwise **or** operator" in C, you should be able to figure out what's going on. If not just a hint: a "bit-wise" operator will perform it's operation on any single bin (instead of on the whole value) ... so `0|1` will be `1`, but also, `10 | 1` will be `11`.